# angular universal not creating tsconfig.server.json file

Tags: angular

Hello I was following along with  a udemy course on angular 2. I had been building my own project along with the course. We got the the angular universal part and the course was a bit outdated with the firebase information so it did not work, I had deleted the files to start installing universal into my app with. But now when i go to run ng add @nguniversal/express-engine it says skipping installation and

```
Could not read 'tsconfig.server.json'.
```

Ive tried uninstalling universal via the terminal and reinstall but it will not create the tsconfig.server.json. any help is greatly appreciated.

edit: have tried uninstalling universal express-engine. the universal map loader and re installing them an still getting the same error. no Idea how to fix this becuase nguniversal should create the tsconfig.server.json file but its not.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up creating a dummy project installing ng universal and copy pasting to make my own tsconfig-server-json file.